# How can I assign seasons based on month in Strptime?

Tags: r

I have thousands of rows in this column. I would like to create a different column with four seasons based on Col 1. The 4 seasons are: SON (Sep, Oct, Nov), MAM (Mar, Apr, May), DJF (Dec, Jan, Feb) and JJA (Jun, Jul, Aug) based on the **month** in Col 1.

```
Col 1               
6/9/2013 1:15      
3/29/2005 21:00    
4/16/2007 15:15
```

So the output would be something like

```
Col 1             Month    Season  
6/9/2013 1:15     June     JJA
3/29/2005 21:00   March    MAM 
4/16/2007 15:15   April    MAM
```

Etc.

I did this,

```
all["month"]<-strptime(all$col1,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$mon
all["monthname"]<-factor(all$month, levels=1:12, labels=month.name)
```

But I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: have you tried the format function to strip the month and then used a series of ifelse statements or cases from the, i think, memisc package?

Comment: Note the the answer to the duplicate converted to POSIXlt and your `t1` object is already a POSIXlt-object since that is what strptime returns.

Comment: I have never used postix before. Trying to understand it. I am able to assign months like (1) all["month"]<-strptime(all$col1,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")$mon (2)all["mont"]<-factor(all$month, levels=1:12, labels=month.name)